# Getting a gradient of a bi-variant function

Tags: java, math, apache-commons-math

I'm doing some video processing, for each frame I need to get a gradient of a bi-variate function.
The function is represented as a two dimensional array of doubles. Where the domain is the rows and columns indices and the range is the double value of the corresponding indices values. Or more simply put, the function `f` is defined for `double[][] matrix` as such:

`f(x,y)=matrix[x][y]`

I'm trying to use the Apache Commons Math library for it:

```
SmoothingPolynomialBicubicSplineInterpolator iterpolator = new SmoothingPolynomialBicubicSplineInterpolator();
BicubicSplineInterpolatingFunction f = iterpolator.interpolate(xs, ys, matrix.getData());
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ans[0].length; j++) {
            ans[i][j] = f.partialDerivativeY(i, j); 
        }
    }
```

- with xs, as a sorted array of the x indices `(0,1,...,matrix.getRowDimension() - 1)`
- ys the same on the columns dimension `(0,1,...,matrix.getColumnDimension() - 1)`

The problem is that for a typical matrix in the size of `150X80` it takes as much as `1.4` seconds to run, which renders it completely irrelevant for my needs. So, as a novice user of this library, and programmatic numeric analysis in general, I want to know:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Is there another, faster, way I can accomplish this task with?
3. Is there another open source library (preferably maven-friendly) that offers a solution?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you need the gradient at every point? That's `omega(NM)` no matter what you do.
2) Why are you interpolating? Have you tried a more direct method of calculating the partial derivatives (which make up the gradient)?
3) Have you profiled where most of those 1.4 seconds go?

Comment: 1. I do need all of these points. 2. I'm interpolating to get a function representation for the commons math API and not because there is a real need for me. 3. the time goes into the interpolate command, but as I see it I must use it in order to use the commons math functions. I'd like to hear about a more direct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Numerical differentiation is an entire topic unto itself, a simple google should bring up enough material for you to work with (just the wiki might be sufficient). There are parameters of your problem that I cannot know, so I can only speak broadly here, but there are direct methods of determining the gradient at a given point, i.e. ones that don't require an interpolation. See the wikipedia for the formulae (ranging from the simple `f(x+1)-f(x)`, which is where `h=1`, to the higher order ones). Calculating the partial derivatives is then a simple `O(NM)` loop with an uber easy formula inside (no interpolation required).

The specifics can get gritty:

1. The higher order formulae need to be reduced for the edges, or
   discarded altogether.
2. Your precise speed requirements might render more complex formulae useless (depending on the platform sometimes the lookup times for higher order formulae make them too slow; again, it depends on the cache etc.). This is easy to test, the formulae are simple; code them and benchmark.
3. The specific implementation is also dependent on your error requirements. The theory provides error bounds, so that will play a role in what formula you need; but again, there's a trade-off with speed requirements. The in turn can be practically lowered if you know specifics about the types of matrices you'll be processing, if such a thing is known.

The implementation can be made even easier (and maybe faster) if you have existing convolution tools, since this method is really just a convolution of the matrix (note; technically it's called a cross-correlation).